# Cannot ssh via ethernet, but can via wifi

Tags: wifi, ssh, ethernet

I am having the exact reverse of the problem described here:[Cannot SSH to Raspberry Pi via WiFi only](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13890/cannot-ssh-to-raspberry-pi-via-wifi-only)

I am able to ssh into the raspberry pi via wifi but not via ethernet. The error message returned is:

```
ssh: connect to host re.local port 22: Connection refused
```

I can ping the ip address.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Do you connect by specifying an IP or domain name? Maybe you configured sshd on raspberry to listen to specific IPs?

Comment: `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and check if `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` is maybe on your wifi ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running "ssh -v user@youriphere". The "-v" stands for verbose output and will tell you a lot more about where the problem is. Post the results here, and you may want to include the contents of your /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem then I found this tutorial: http://blogs.arcsoftwareconsultancy.com/pi/2013/03/07/windows-networking/
I followed all the steps and I can now do network and ssh.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a silly issue..  I was on 2 different networks.

Issue the command `ifconfig` and inspect the assigned IP values.

*Then proceed as I did with a face-palm..*  :)